# How to make a raycast collide against the same layers as a layer in the Physics Manager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my Physics.Raycast to collide with the same "Layers" name as the I've set up in Physics Manager. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

All [Raycast methods](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) allow you to specify a layerMask. All you need is to find the proper int value for your layer and provide it as an argument.

That would look something like this:

```
int layerMask = LayerMask.NameToLayer("MyLayerName");
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask)) 
{
    //I hit something somewhere that is on my layer
}
```

And given that they are bit masks, you can of course specify masks for any combination of layers you'd like to include or exclude.